# notes on properties of chern character of coherent sheaves

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm trying to understand a bit about chern classes/chern characters (in the algebraic setting, for varieties over C say) and was hoping to find some notes describing some well-known properties of ch (e.g. the relation between the support of a coherent sheaf and the component of ch of the same dimension).

I'm really hoping of something in the middle between Hartshorne's appendix and say Fulton's intersection theory (or Fulton-Lang RR algebra), which concentrates more on coherent sheaves.

(I know, I'm asking too much)

Comment: is there a way to community-wiki this question?

Comment: Done.  (Users can't set their own questions to CW anymore, but moderators still can.)